# Navigating between 2 react-router-v4 projects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, react-router, react-router-v4

I have 2 different ReactJS projects installed in the same server. They are located in different directories estructures:

```
/var/www/myapps/app1 -> My 1st application
/var/www/myapps/app2 -> My 2nd application
```

I'm using nginx as web server.

Both applications has the same react-router structure:

```
<BrowserRouter basename={baseName}>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/logout" component={Logout} />
        <Route exact path="/auth" component={Logout} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={NavComponent} />
        <Route exact path="/:screen" component={NavComponent} />
        <Route
            exact
            path="/:screen/:action"
            component={NavComponent}
        />
        <Route
            exact
            path="/:screen/:action/:id"
            component={NavComponent}
        />

        <Route component={PageNotFoundError} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Where `baseName` changes is either `app1` (1st application) or `app2` (2nd application).

Both applications has components to navigate using `react-router-v4` `withRouter()` wrapper function. These components uses:
`this.props.history.push("/whatever")` or `this.props.history.push(0)` or `this.props.history.push(-1)`.

I have also components (like buttons) that changes between applications, using `windows.location = "/app1/whatever"` or `window.location = "app2/whatever"`

The strange error I'm getting is after pressing a button that changes from one application to another. Putting in sequence:

1. User loads `app1` and navigates inside it using all kinds of functions - All fine
2. User clicks on button to change to `app2` (this button uses `windows.location` function) - All fine
3. User navigates inside `app2` using `this.props.history.push("/whatever")` - All fine
4. User clicks on refresh button for some `app2` screen (using  `this.props.history.go(0)`) - breaks, trying to load clicked link but in old application context.

Seems that after `window.location` the router history get messed up, even loading a new router.

Comment: Why don't you use `window.location.reload()` to refresh the page?

Comment: Does it mean we also can use reload button on the browser?